# How to read the ref code from URL in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get the ref code from the URL, http://localhost:3000/?ref=2926

I try with const session = `${window.location.href}`; it gets the full current URL and tries to use split() the pathname but it didn't work, how to get only the ref code from the URL.

Comment: are you using [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)? if yes you should check [this](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/query-strings-search-params-react-router) . If not then you should use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
${window.location.search.split('=')[1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You also get value of ref from this way  :

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const parameters = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const value = parameters.get('ref');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser native api

```
const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
console.log(query.get(ref))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

- `const { searchParams } = new URL(document.location)`

Code:

```js
const { searchParams } = new URL('http://localhost:3000/?ref=2926')
console.log(searchParams.get('ref'))
```

React component:

```
export const UrlSearchParamValue = ({ name }) => {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(document.location)
  const value = searchParams.get(name)
  return <span>{value}</span>
};
```

To use:

```
<UrlSearchParamValue name='ref' />
```